# maven dependencies and jetty - avoiding deploy

Tags: java, jetty, maven

I have a project with 3 artifacts:

common - entities, business logic.  no UI code
webapp-a  - a public web app
webapp-b  - an admin web app

webapp-a and webapp-b depend on common.  common is configured to deploy to a local maven repo.

so far so good.

I have IntelliJ configured so that each artifact is a separate module.  Module dependencies are configured properly.  I can add a new method to a class in common and immediately use that method in a class in a webapp.

However, when I run `mvn jetty:run` it uses the currently deployed common snapshot in my repository.  It does not use my local classes.  If I add a method to a class in common, it compiles fine, but blows up at runtime.

So is it possible to either:

a) Convince `jetty:run` to use my local common build output

or

b) Deploy my common output to my local `~/.m2/repo` while I'm testing locally before I want to commit/deploy

or

c) some other solution?

thank you!

-- James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `mvn jetty:run` then your common module must be installed. Maven won't pick your unpackaged/uninstalled classes.

The alternative I'm using is simply running Jetty direct from the IDE as a pseudo-unit test. Here's a [sample project](http://confluence.highsource.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5013538) if you wish. The `RunDemoHelloWorld` (runnable with JUnit) starts Jetty directly from Eclipse. Should work in IDEA as well.